# Inversion in factor rings

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I have this polynomials: 
$f = x^{4} + 3x^{3} + x^2 + 3 \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, 
$g = x + 2  \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$

Does g + (f) have inversion in ring $(\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/(f),+,.)$ ?

I should found it or prove that it doesn't exist.
I don't know how to start with this, could you give me some hint please?

I guess I should start with proving that polynomial f is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$
but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division algorithm will give
$$
x^4+3x^3+x^2+3=(x+2)(x^3+x^2-x+2)-1.
$$
Thus
$$
(x+2)(x^3+x^2-x+2)=(x^4+3x^3+x^2+3) +1.
$$

EDIT: By dividing $f$ by $x+2$ you find a polynomial $p$ such that 
$$
(x+2)p(x)=f(x)+1.
$$
But, $f(x)+1$ represents the unit in $(\mathbb{Z}/5)[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand why i should divide this polynomials. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Krivers I edited it to add more detail.

Comment: Sorry I think I am sleeping, because I think that I don't fully understand you. This is a prove that polynomial is in the ring? How can I found the inverse of the polynomial? I think that it should be throught Bézout's identity.

Comment: What I proved is that $x^3+x^2-x+2$ is the inverse.

Comment: oh I see thank you so much